# Not able to print index values of different rows using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

import numpy as np

Create a 2-D array

```
x=np.arange(10)

print(x)

x.shape=(2,5) #Means 2 rows and 5 elements(columns) in each row

print("Print the newly made 2-D array")

print(x)

print(x[np.array([0,1]),np.array([3,2,4])])
```

On running the code, it gives:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

print(x[np.array([0,1]),np.array([3,2,4])]) 

IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (3,)
```

Comment: The 2 indexing arrays have to `broadcast` against each other (imagine the indexing equivalent of adding 2 arrays). A (2,) and a (3,) don't work.  A (2,1) will work with a (1,3) to select (2,3) points.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [122]: x= np.arange(10).reshape(2,5)
In [123]: x
Out[123]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
In [124]: x[np.array([0,1]),:]
Out[124]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
In [125]: x[:,np.array([3,2,4])]
Out[125]: 
array([[3, 2, 4],
       [8, 7, 9]])
```

Indexing with 2 arrays:

```
In [126]: x[np.array([0,1]),np.array([3,2,4])]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [126] in <cell line: 1>
    x[np.array([0,1]),np.array([3,2,4])]
IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (3,)
```

But if one is (2,1) shape, then:

```
In [127]: x[np.array([0,1])[:,None],np.array([3,2,4])]
Out[127]: 
array([[3, 2, 4],
       [8, 7, 9]])
```

Note that this is the sames [125] which uses `slice` for the rows.

The key issue is `broadcasting`.  It's powerful, but a little hard for beginners to grasp.  A way to visualize this `broadcasting` is to add the 2 arrays:

```
In [128]: np.array([0,1])[:,None]*10 + np.array([3,2,4])
Out[128]: 
array([[ 3,  2,  4],
       [13, 12, 14]])
```

If the 2 arrays have the same length, we get a "diagonal" of the [125] box:

```
In [129]: x[np.array([0,1]),np.array([3,2])]
Out[129]: array([3, 7])
```

### Reference

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html